# Prevent IIS from changing response when Location header is present

Tags: php, iis, rest, iis-7

I have a RESTful web service written in a PHP-based framework running on IIS which responds to a POST request with something like

```
Status: 201 Created
Location: [url of created object]
Content-length: [correct]

{ my: "created object" }
```

It seems because of the Location header IIS is adding text to the response so it becomes (HTML removed for clarity):

```
Status: 201 Created
Location: [url of created object]
Content-length: [incorrect!]

Document Moved
Object Moved This document may be found here
{ my: "created object" }
```

I don't mind the addition of the text so much, but IIS seems to be keeping the original content-length while changing the content, creating an invalid response and thus causing the consumer of the web service to give me a protocol violation error.

Is there a way to prevent IIS from mangling my response?

**Edit:** Never did find an answer - I ended up switching to Apache

Comment: I have the exact same trouble and it's driving me insane!!!

Comment: Me also. There's still no solution to this in IIS? (I don't consider "switch to apache" a solution)