# W7 Pro IIS 7.5 overwrites PHP Location: Header

Tags: php, rest, iis, http-headers

I am creating a RESTful API in PHP, and have encountered a problem.
When the client is posting data to the server, the server should return:

```
Status code 201 CREATED
Header Location with the location of the new object
Content-Type application/xml

<SomeXmlData></SomeXmlData>
```

Dummy code, producing the problem on my computer:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://google.no/",true,201);
header("Content-Type: application/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n";
echo "<Jada></Jada>";
?>
```

The HTTP result is

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://google.no/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 22 Aug 2012 13:52:57 GMT
Content-Length: 209

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://google.no/">here</a></body><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Jada></Jada>
```

PHP automatically adds some HTML code, and HTML content-type to the response, because of the location header.

Because of this, my api won't work with its clients.

EDIT:
IIS 7.5 Windows 7 Proffesional

Comment: Why do your content-type header and XML declaration disagree about the character encoding?

Comment: I think that's your server doing it, not PHP.

Comment: `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.5 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET`? Every time I see something related to IIS, I want to run screaming.

Comment: That's most certainly *not* raw PHP doing that. Needs better diagnostics and/or more info to be answerable.

Comment: Tried on my local server with Apache: sending a `Location` header does not produce automatic HTML. However, one should note that Apache will complain if you use `http://example.com/dir` instead of `http://example.com/dir/` and output similar HTML: IIS might be doing that, too.

Comment: ...why do you `echo` the XML? Why not just close the PHP tag?

Comment: It is dummy code.... The character-encoding and closing of PHP-tags is not priority in this code, just to show the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to create an IIS module, that rewrites the header "Custom-Location" to "Location" after FastCGI is done.

Then, FastCGI won't know that we are sending a Location header at all, and it won't modify my response.

The module:

```
string Location = context.Response.Headers["Custom-Location"] as string;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Location))
{
    context.Response.Headers.Remove("Custom-Location");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Location", Location);
}
```

PHP:

```
header("Custom-Location: http://google.no",true,201);
header("Content-Type: application/xml");
echo "<xml></xml>";
```

(still dummy code, not extremly correct code :) )

Comment: I want to make some clarification. It is all about handlers not modules. We faced the same problem when IIS prepended some HTML into content. Another interesting but not obvious thing that you still can creat managed handlers for PHP environment deployed on your IIS. It is same as creating any other http handlers written in managed code.

Comment: I don't understand what is going on here. Can you explain how does this fix the issue in iis?

Comment: The problem is that the IIS handler is modifing the HTTP response body when the Location header is present. Our solution was to send 'Custom-Location' instead, then the IIS handler will not do anything about that. Then, I made an IIS module that rewrites the 'Custom-Location' header to 'Location' - this logic is after the handler logic, so the handler will not modify the response body.

Comment: This answer is four years old, we are not using IIS anymore, so I cannot tell if this still works.

Answer (score 5):

I am sorry to bear bad news, but look here:

[Prevent IIS from changing response when Location header is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594225/prevent-iis-from-changing-response-when-location-header-is-present)

> Edit: Never did find an answer - I ended up switching to Apache

And it seems IIS has had its fingers into headers for a long time:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1158431.aspx

> This is a bug in IIS FastCGI module. It will be fixed in Windows 7 RTM. We are also looking into possible ways for making this fix available for IIS 7.

Hopefully **if** the bugs are related (I expect they are), **if** you now have FastCGI, *then* the fix below could work. Otherwise, switching to PHP non-FastCGI module might also work, and it might be easier than throwing in with Apache.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980363

Comment: Thank you. I eventually gave up, and made an iis module that fixes the problem.

Comment: +1 for a clever workaround. (Is it possible to downvote Microsoft?)

Comment: The problem still occurs in IIS 8.5.9600.16384 / Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with WP REST API on IIS 8.5. Following html

```
<head>
    <title>Document Moved</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Object Moved</h1>
    This document may be found 
    <a HREF="[url-from-location-header]">here</a>
</body>
```

was added at start of every json returned with `Location` header and status `201 Created`. `Content-Type` was changed to `text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Adding `cgi.rfc2616_headers = 1` in php.ini resulted with:

- clean body (json) without added html
- correct "Content-Type"
- "Location" header missing
- Status chaged to `200 OK`

I wouldn't call this solution, this is more replacing one problem with another. Luckily this new problem in my situation was smaller than original one.

Comment: I'm running into this issue with a flask-restless api (python) on IIS. Could you explain in more detail how you fixed the issue using iis?

Comment: In my opinion forcing rfc2616 headers is not a valid solution because many PHP applications rely on apache headers, e.g. wordpress.

Comment: Do you remember if you were returning a relative URL (/a/b/c...) or an absolute URL (https://...) in the Location header?

Answer (score 1):

To circumvent this IIS behavior, you can use an outbound rewrite rule. The following will look for status 201, and if so, eliminate all the content lines up to and including the closing body tag:

```
<outboundRules>
  <rule name="Remove injected 201 content" preCondition="Status 201">
    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="^(?:.*[\r\n]*)*.*&lt;/body>" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
  </rule>
  <preConditions>
   <preCondition name="Status 201" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
     <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="201" ignoreCase="false" />
   </preCondition>
  </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: This rule crashed w3wp (on a 201 status), (IIS 8 on server 2012). It doesn't like the regex pattern. I created two separate rules on the same precondition, one for the head (pattern "\*.head>") and one for the body (pattern "\*.body>") and it solves the problem