# Tastypie in IIS returns HTML instead of JSON

Tags: python, ajax, django, iis, tastypie

When issuing a POST to Tastypie (Django) to add a new "project" object to my database, the following code works fine outside of IIS, in debug mode.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://webserver.com/api/v1/project/",
    type: "POST",
    data: jsonProject
    ...
    success: do something with the response object
```

Note:  I'm using "always_return_data = True" in Tastypie to return the newly created object back to the client.

HOWEVER, when I publish the same code to IIS, and run the application, Tastypie returns the following HTML w/ the JSON object appended to the end.  Does anyone have any theories as to why this might be happening, and more importantly, how to keep IIS from prepending this HTML?

```
"<head><title>Document Moved</title></head><body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://localhost/api/v1/project/14/">here</a></body>{"id": 14, "name": "New Project", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/project/14/", "slug": "new-project", "start_date": null, "status": 0}"
```

I am able to solve the problem by splitting the response on the  tag, but this isn't a very graceful hack, to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tastypie will return a `Location` header every time you create a new resource, pointing to it (which is the `http://localhost/api/v1/project/14/` url you're seeing returned in the response).

I'm not sure exactly how you're running django on IIS, but I suspect your problem might be similar if not the same as the problem described here:
[W7 Pro IIS 7.5 overwrites PHP Location: Header (solved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074730/w7-pro-iis-7-5-overwrites-php-location-header-solved)