# Yii2 REST API IIS Object Moved

Tags: windows, rest, api, iis, yii2

I am using Yii2 REST with **ActiveController** to create a **new Pessoa()**, on Apache works fine , but on IIS 8 an error occurs.

Does anyone know of any configuration in IIS?

> REQUEST

```
Request URL:http://10.192.1.145/api/pessoa
Request Method:POST
Status Code:201 Created
Remote Address:10.192.1.145
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

> RESPONSE

```
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found 
<a HREF="http://10.192.1.145/api/pessoa/45">here</a></body>{"id":"21"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this. It seems to be related to FastCGI. Not sure about it. I know it happens when setting response headers to 201 http status code ([this line in source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/c19b2f7dc8f487f0a867f2cacab68b8e86b7a8f9/framework/rest/CreateAction.php#L54)) which get changed by IIS later. If you have access to server try those solutions:

> [W7 Pro IIS 7.5 overwrites PHP Location: Header (solved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074730/w7-pro-iis-7-5-overwrites-php-location-header-solved)

In my case I had only FTP access to server so I overridden the Create Action by something like what follows to force a 200 status code instead of 201:

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    unset($actions['create']);
    return $actions;
}

public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Pessoa();
    $model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');
    if ($model->save() === false && !$model->hasErrors()) {
        throw new ServerErrorHttpException('Failed to update the object for unknown reason.');
    }
    return $model;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else needs to **keep the status code** and **remove only the response part added by IIS**, this is what I did to solve my problem. You may need adapt it to your needs, though:

```
<!-- PS: In my case, i just had a one line HEAD and a one line BODY being added. -->

<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Remove the tag HEAD" preCondition="isStatus201">
        <match filterByTags="None" pattern="^\&lt;head\&gt;.*?$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Remove the tag BODY" preCondition="isStatus201">
        <match filterByTags="None" pattern="^\&lt;body\&gt;.*?\&lt;/body\&gt;" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="isStatus201">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="^201$" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Tested in IIS 8.5;

Hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I was able to optimize the RegEx so that a single rule catches all the lines up the closing body tag:

```
<outboundRules>
  <rule name="Remove injected 201 content" preCondition="Status 201">
    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="^(?:.*[\r\n]*)*.*&lt;/body>" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
  </rule>
  <preConditions>
   <preCondition name="Status 201" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
     <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="201" ignoreCase="false" />
   </preCondition>
  </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```